# Readline function returning the first line

Tags: python

Relatively inexperienced Python user here, I was trying to use the **readline** function for a project in order to read a specific line of an *.xyz* file.

However, no matter what the argument of the **readline** function I enter, it systematically returns the first line.

Any idea what could cause this, and how to fix it?

Here is the *cube.xyz* file:

```
4  

'Cu' 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5  
'Ag' 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.5  
'Ag' 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.5  
'Cu' 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.5
```

And the bit of code supposed to read it:

```
def swapfunction ():
    inp = open('cube.xyz', 'r+')
    print inp.readline(3)

swapfunction()
```

Which returns:

```
>>> 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: that is what `readline()` does. You either have to use multiple of those (subsequent uses read further and further in the document) or set the pointer to somewhere *deeper* in the file.

Comment: The question is, what do you _want_ it to return?

Comment: the argument passed to `readline()` is the size (number of bytes) not the line number

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I guess the 3rd line, or even better a function where he can just pass a number and the number becomes the line to read.

Comment: Oh, I see. I got the argument wrong. All right, thank you for your help.

Comment: @PaulG. Take a look at `linecache` and `linecache.getline()`. [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inp.readline(n)` returns either the entire line, or the number of bytes in the current line, whichever is lesser. If you want to read by bytes, I suggest you use `inp.read(n)`. Alternatively, use a loop over `inp`

```
def swapfunction ():
    inp = open('cube.xyz', 'r+')
    for line in inp:
        print line,

swapfunction()
```

Output:

```
4  

'Cu' 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5  
'Ag' 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.5  
'Ag' 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.5  
'Cu' 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def swapfunction():
    with open('cube.xyz', 'r+') as inp:
        lines = inp.readlines()
```

Then you'd have `lines` in a list, which you can index freely.

Or if you have a big file, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
import itertools

def swapfunction():
    with open('cube.xyz', 'r+') as inp:
        index = 3
        line = next(itertools.islice(inp, index, index + 1))
```

Comment: Bad idea for large files